# Statistical test to compare two groups: Does my proposed process make sense?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, t-test, differences

Here is the situation. I am facing a comparison problem where I am trying to compare an insulated pipe with a non insulated pipe. I need to test if the use of insulation creates a significant difference in heat loss. There are also multiple pipes which in each group (insulated and non-insulated).

I have temperature sensors at the inlet and outlet of each pipe which I am collecting transient temperature data.

Also, the flow through the pipes is not steady state and is prone to fluctuations and on top of all of this, the pipes are not the same length.

What I was thinking was the following:

1. For each pipe, take the difference between the inlet and outlet
   temperature difference for each point in time for the duration of
   sampling.
2. Determine the mean of each inlet/outlet difference
3. Normalize the mean of differences by pipe length.
4. Sort the pipes into groupings of insulated and non-insulated.
5. Perform a one tailed 2-sample t-tests with my alternative hypothesis
   being that the mean of the insulated group is less than the
   non-insulated group.

That is my rough procedure. I am not too experienced with statistics and am worried that I am missing something. If someone could maybe comment on the validity of what I am doing or potentially propose an alternative method for analysis it would be very greatly appreciated!

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. Is temperature decline of a fluid moving through a pipe supposed to be linear in the length of the pipe? Normalizing by the length seems like a reasonable thing to do, but I'm not a physics guy and don't know. One obvious way this can be misleading is if your insulated pipes tend to be different on some dimension other than insulation (eg. the insulated pipes tend to be all iron etc...).

Comment: Something else if you want to get fancy: I imagine your estimates for the longer pipes will be more precise than the estimates for your short pipes. Instead of taking the straight average, you could give greater weight to the estimates from the longer pipes. (The optimal thing from a GLS generalized least squares perspective would be to weight proportional to 1/variance of the observation).

Comment: I am not sure taking the difference is good. Surely fluid at the temperature of the environment would not change temperature and hotter would get colder,  while colder would get hotter?  Why not model outlet temperature and use inlet temperature and pipe length as (not necessarily linear) covariates? Also do you have information on the environment of the pipes  (e.g. outside in the Sahara vs. inside in a freezer)?

Comment: @Mat I wouldn't expect the difference to be linear in the length of the pipe (except as 1st order approximation). I'd expect the temperature at the halfway point to be at least a bit nearer the temperature at the outlet end than the inlet end (because [most of the heat transfer would happen initially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_cooling#Temperature_function-of-time_solution_in_terms_of_object_heat_capacity), temperature differences in the pipe material would take a while to "flow" along the pipe). [Allowing time between measuring inlet vs outlet might make it nearly linear.]